# InteropBitmap synchronization

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

WPF InteropBitmap can be created from shared memory, i.e.

```
Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection()
```

In this case, we can update shared memory in another thread or process, and then after updating, calling **InteropBitmap.Invalidate()** to present the changes.

From the WPF source code, InteropBitmap is just a wrapper of IWICBitmap, but it doesn't expose [IWICBitmap::lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690187%28VS.85%29.aspx) which is used for exclusive writing.

So, how do I sync writing and reading of WPF InteropBitmap?

1. Updating occurs in user's thread.
2. Reading always occurs in WPF internal render thread via [IWICBitmapSource::CopyPixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690179%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can create a WrapperClass which exposed a lock object and the methods to manipulate the Image. Is some work but would work 100%

something like:

```
class InteropBitmapSyncWrapper
{

    public InteropBitmapSyncWrapper(InteropBitmap wrappedBitmap)
    {
        WrappedBitmap = wrappedBitmap;
        this.Lock = new Object();
    }

    public InteropBitmap WrappedBitmap
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Object Lock
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```